# How to discover what the missing progressive arithmetic number missing in the List<Integer> is in Java 8?

Tags: java, search, java-8

I have a huge list of numbers in a sequence but one number is missing. How can I find out what the gap number missing is with efficiency using Java 8+?

I did just like this:

```
public class PAMissingNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);  //imagine that this list is huge    
        Collections.sort(listInteger);
        int result = 0;
        int sequence = listInteger.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < listInteger.size(); i++) {
            if (sequence!= listInteger.get(i)) {
                result = sequence;
                break;
            } else {
                sequence++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The missing number is : " + result);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to code this more efficiently?

Comment: If I pick a number between 1 and 100 and you have to guess it, and I can only answer by "it's lower" or "it's higher", how do you proceed? Apply the same technique here.

Comment: You can do it much faster using binary search if the list is sorted.

Comment: Is the list sorted?

Comment: @GBlodgett/Kartik The list of values must be sorted given that it's an arithmetic progression. Do take a quick look at [it's wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) if curious still.

Comment: @Alexandre If you know a common difference and the size of the list, there is no harm in performing a binary search there either and you shouldn't really require `.sort` if the input is an arithmetic progression.

Comment: @Naman or if you list always start with `1` and there are no duplicates, it's even easier

Comment: hey @Kartik I have heard that binary search would be very interesting. I will search about it but I would appreciated if anyone contribute.

Comment: Hey @GBlodgett. it is not a sorted list. My example was sorted but I can not expect it.

Comment: Actually it is an arithmetic progression @Naman I will search how to implement binary search. Thank you

Comment: Binary search only helps when the list is already sorted, which you just ruled out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Eugene’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55295247/2711488) is pointing into the right direction. If the list is not sorted and does not always start with one, the generalized solution is

```
IntSummaryStatistics iss = listInteger.stream()
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();
long from = iss.getMin(), to = iss.getMax(), sum = iss.getSum();
int diff = (int)((from+to)*(to-from+1)/2 - sum);
System.out.println(diff);
```

An alternative is to use a `BitSet`:

```
BitSet bs = listInteger.stream().collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or);
System.out.println(bs.nextClearBit(bs.nextSetBit(0)));
```

This does need some temporary storage, but has the advantage of still working even when more than one value is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers start with `1`, if actually very easy.

The sum of all numbers is computed by a formula: `x(x+1)/2`, meaning if your list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`:

```
  sum = 10 * 11 / 2 = 55;
```

All you have to do is add all your numbers and do a difference (this also implies that there are no duplicate numbers in your list):

```
 List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

 int max = Collections.max(listInteger);
 int sum = max * (max + 1) / 2;
 int diff = sum - listInteger.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
 System.out.println(diff);
```

Taking into consideration the good comment from Kartik, this can be written as:

```
List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8);

    IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics =
        listInteger.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));
    int max = summaryStatistics.getMax();
    int min = summaryStatistics.getMin();
    int sum = (int) summaryStatistics.getSum();

    System.out.println((max - min + 1) * (max + min) / 2 - sum);
```

Comment: Summing all the numbers in the list is still O(n). Just like the original solution, but less obvious.

Comment: Hi @Eugene! Awesome solution! Thank you very much! I don't know reputation enough to like it but I would like to fix in case the list of numbers are: 
private List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10);

Comment: @AlexandreBarbosa well find the `min` (3 in your case), sum from 1 to that min (1 + 2 = 3), sum from 1 to 10 (55) in your case; do 55 - 3 = 52; 52 - (3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 8 + 9 + 10) = 7.

Comment: _"If your numbers start with 1"_ - Even if they don't start with 1, and even if the numbers increment/decrement by a number other than 1, the [formula for sum of arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) will still work.

Comment: @Kartik indeed, I totally forgot about this basic math, thank you; updated the answer also